# Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn causes error "e.getAuthType is not a function"

Tags: javascript, facebook, parse-platform

I've created a very simple JS/HTML site with Parse, and I'm trying to login with Facebook using the Parse JS SDK.

I simply call Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn when a button is clicked.  I see the Facebook dialog, but after authorization, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.getAuthType is not a function
  s.value @ parse-1.6.0.min.js:13
  s.value.e.authenticate.success @ parse1.6.0.min.js:13
  r.default.init.l.default._registerAuthenticationProvider.authenticate.FB.login.scope @ parse-1.6.0.min.js:11
  window.FB.v.__wrapper @ sdk.js:98
  etc
```

Here's my very simple code that's exercising this API:

```
Parse.initialize(
  "abc",
  "xyz");

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  Parse.FacebookUtils.init({ // this line replaces FB.init({
    appId      : '1234', // Facebook App ID
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow Parse to access the session
    xfbml      : true,  // initialize Facebook social plugins on the page
    version    : 'v2.3' // point to the latest Facebook Graph API version
  });
};
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#facebook-login').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn("email", {
      success: function(user) {
        if (!user.existed()) {
          console.log("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
        } else {
          console.log("User logged in through Facebook!");
        }
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        console.log("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
      }
    });
  });
});

(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the latest release (1.6.0) of the Parse Javascript SDK

Load the earlier one and it will work:

`<script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.5.0.min.js"></script>`

Although clearly a bug, you can find more information on the release here: https://parse.com/docs/downloads

Comment: looks like FB is working on it: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/882121675197813/